# grep: Find all patterns like obj && obj.propery

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I need to change in a code all the places which look like:

```
obj && obj.property && obj.subproperty
```

with

```
_.get(obj, 'property.subproperty')
```

I believe I can find all such occurrences with grep and some regexp. So, can somebody help me with regexp?

example of an occurrence:

```
  if (thing.reported &&
    thing.reported.payload &&
    thing.reported.payload.metadata &&
    thing.reported.payload.metadata.position) {
```

I'm finished with regexp like this:

```
/(.+?)[^a-zA-Z\d].?\1.(.+?)[^a-zA-Z\d].?\1.\2.(.+?)[^a-zA-Z\d]/gim
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this:

```
(\S+)\s*&&\s*\1\.\S+
```

This matches all objects followed with && followed by the same object with a . and something else.

If you want to use it with grep you need to remove the newlines because grep can't deal with those.

```
cat test.js| tr -d '\n'  | grep -P '(\S+)\s*&&\s*\1\.\S+'
```

Comment: There is no '-P' flag on mac. What should it mean?

Comment: -P stands for PCRE regex. But apparently it got removed on mac. But the regex also seems to work on -E (extended) regex with grep.

Answer (score 1):

In vim, this

```
:%s/\s*if\s*(\_.\{-} &&\_\s*\(.\{-}\)\.\(.*\)\s*)\s*{/_.get(\1, \2)/
```

Will transform the example of an occurrence into :

```
_.get(thing, reported.payload.metadata.position)
```

To explain a bit :

- %s/ : to try to match in all the file (important with multi-line matches)
- \s* : means any number of white spaces (or tabs).
- \_. : means any character including newline.
- \{-} : means that what is before will be matched the least number of occurences possible
- \. : means a real dot
- \(\) : that how to make capturing parenthesis in vim

Comment: And you may open all your files in vim with : vim *.code-files

Comment: And you can apply the substitution scheme in all files with: :argdo %s/foo/bar/ | wq

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
search: obj && obj\.(\w+) && obj\.(\w+)
replace: _.get(obj, '$1.$2')
```

Does obj need to be different too in each case?

If the depth is variable, I don't think there's a general solution with regexes.